# webpack style-loader - import different styles on react components without overriding

Tags: javascript, styles, reactjs, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I have 2 React components which require styles inside:

product list:

```
import './list.css';
import React from 'react';

export default class List extends React.Component {
   ...
}
```

product details:

```
import './details.css';
import React from 'react';

export default class Details extends React.Component {
   ...
}
```

And they have different styles which override one another, for simplicity lets assume it's `background-color` property on `body`:

list.css

```
body {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
```

details.css

```
body {
    background-color: #f80;
}
```

What is actually happening - styles are kept on the page for both of the elements when bundled by webpack's style-loader:

```
<style type="text/css">
body {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
body {
    background-color: #f80;
}
</style>
```

webpack configuration for loader:

```
...
{
   test: /\.css$/,
   loader: 'style?singleton!css!cssnext'
}
```

That means that detail's style are active on list page as well. What's is the best strategy to keep them different? Is there a way for styles to be replaced?

Answer (score 0):

When you are using **style loader**. you can use the the useable api they provide. You can read about it [here](https://github.com/webpack/style-loader#recommended-configuration).

All the conflicting css can be put in `.useable.css` and create one more loader for those files using the useable api.

```
{
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.css$/, exclude: /\.useable\.css$/, loader: "style!css" },
      { test: /\.useable\.css$/, loader: "style/useable!css" }
    ]
  }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

use isomorphic-style-loader in stead of style-loader. It will namespace your classnames with component name and keep the styles unique. So composability, uniqueness and critical styles can be maintained. More on this: https://github.com/kriasoft/isomorphic-style-loader